# Would I be allowed to link to my own published papers, if relevant to the question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If strictly to do with the topic, could I give a link to one of my own published papers as an example?

Comment: Wouldn't this be so exceptional that the question would be closed as "too localized" anyway?

Comment: perhaps, it is unlikely that it would be needed to be done.

Comment: [Yes.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10271/can-one-publish-papers-which-give-an-improved-presentation-of-old-results#comment18663_10271)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So long as the paper and the link coherently fit into your answer, as well as the topic of the question, I don't see a problem with this. You can make a disclaimer if you want, and I think that would satisfy any concerns.

Comment: Good idea about the disclaimer - I would imagine that this would be a very occasional occurrence.

Comment: +1 for disclaimer. I think thats an important step.